# What's the WSDLIMP.EXE command line to import BasicHttpBinding WSDL into Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-7

I've downloaded the updated wsdlimp.exe from http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535

What's the WSDLIMP.EXE command line (which commandline options) to import BasicHttpBinding WSDL into Delphi 7? I tried the basic syntax but the generated pas file won't even compile!

Comment: Can you post the url or the wsdl you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line is simply

```
wsdlimp -P service.wsdl
```

No special comman-line options are necessary.

The problem was that the wsdl was specifying wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding (that's why it wouldn't compile in Delphi7).

The wsdl I'd previously posted was an old example that happened to be correct (ie. using basicHttpBinding and WCFExtras single file endpoint behaviour extensions), that's why Jeroen was able to import it. I cannot provide the real wsdl I'm working with for legal reasons, but suffice to say that once I'd configured the service to use basicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding, and used the single file endpoint behaviour provided by WCFExtras (as described here: [How to create a single WSDL file from existing WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216624/how-to-create-a-single-wsdl-file-from-existing-wcf-service) ), the wsdl could then be imported successfully into a Delphi 7 project.

Comment: +1; Thanks for the update on this. Good to know what did get you going.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing WSDL generated with Visual Studio 2005 or higher in a standard fashion, you need a newer version of the Delphi WSDL importer as [posted at codecentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24535) by [Jean-Marie Babet](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Jean-Marie%20Babet%22%20wsdl).

Few languages can import everything you can do in WSDL, so you might be out of luck for some details. 
He is the guy that knows most about the WSDL innards and active on the Embarcadero forums, so it is good to ask the same question there too.

The old Delphi WSDL importer only did RCP style SOAP, whereas the new one also supports document/literal style.

See also [this thread](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/5/344800.html).

Memory served me right: that particular issue was solved in Delphi 2007.

*Edit:*

I took a shortcut with the Delphi XE WSDL importer through the IDE noting the options.

Options used:

```
-Oa
-Od
-Oe
-Of
-Oh
-Oi
-Oj
-Oo
-Op
-Ot
-Ou
-Ov
-Ox
```

Imported file:

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : C:\develop\codeplex.svn\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\WSDLSampleImport\wsdl\sampleWsdl.wsdl
//  >Import : C:\develop\codeplex.svn\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\WSDLSampleImport\wsdl\sampleWsdl.wsdl>0
//  >Import : C:\develop\codeplex.svn\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\WSDLSampleImport\wsdl\sampleWsdl.wsdl>1
//  >Import : C:\develop\codeplex.svn\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\WSDLSampleImport\wsdl\sampleWsdl.wsdl>2
// Encoding : utf-8
// Version  : 1.0
// (4/5/2011 1:23:46 PM - - $Rev: 34800 $)
// ************************************************************************ //

unit sampleWsdl;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_REF  = $0080;


type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:boolean         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  CompositeType2       = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService"[GblCplx] }
  CompositeType        = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService"[GblElm] }



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : CompositeType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService
  // ************************************************************************ //
  CompositeType2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FBoolValue: Boolean;
    FBoolValue_Specified: boolean;
    FStringValue: string;
    FStringValue_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetBoolValue(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
    function  BoolValue_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetStringValue(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  StringValue_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property BoolValue:   Boolean  Index (IS_OPTN) read FBoolValue write SetBoolValue stored BoolValue_Specified;
    property StringValue: string   Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read FStringValue write SetStringValue stored StringValue_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : CompositeType, global, <element>
  // Namespace : http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService
  // ************************************************************************ //
  CompositeType = class(CompositeType2)
  private
  published
  end;


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // soapAction: http://tempuri.org/IService1/%operationName%
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // use       : literal
  // binding   : BasicHttpBinding_IService1
  // service   : Service1
  // port      : BasicHttpBinding_IService1
  // URL       : http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/Service1/
  // ************************************************************************ //
  IService1 = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{33335FCB-4DFB-92EA-D063-AF625AFEE0FC}']
    function  GetData(const value: string): string; stdcall;
    function  GetDataUsingDataContract(const composite: CompositeType2): CompositeType2; stdcall;
  end;

function GetIService1(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): IService1;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetIService1(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IService1;
const
  defWSDL = 'C:\develop\codeplex.svn\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\WSDLSampleImport\wsdl\sampleWsdl.wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFService/Service1/';
  defSvc  = 'Service1';
  defPrt  = 'BasicHttpBinding_IService1';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IService1);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure CompositeType2.SetBoolValue(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
begin
  FBoolValue := ABoolean;
  FBoolValue_Specified := True;
end;

function CompositeType2.BoolValue_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FBoolValue_Specified;
end;

procedure CompositeType2.SetStringValue(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
begin
  FStringValue := Astring;
  FStringValue_Specified := True;
end;

function CompositeType2.StringValue_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FStringValue_Specified;
end;

initialization
  { IService1 }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IService1), 'http://tempuri.org/', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(IService1), 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/%operationName%');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(IService1), ioDocument);
  { IService1.GetData }
  InvRegistry.RegisterMethodInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetData', '',
                                 '[ReturnName="GetDataResult"]', IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetData', 'value', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetData', 'GetDataResult', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  { IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract }
  InvRegistry.RegisterMethodInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetDataUsingDataContract', '',
                                 '[ReturnName="GetDataUsingDataContractResult"]', IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetDataUsingDataContract', 'composite', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService"]', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IService1), 'GetDataUsingDataContract', 'GetDataUsingDataContractResult', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService"]', IS_NLBL);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(CompositeType2, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService', 'CompositeType2', 'CompositeType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(CompositeType, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFService', 'CompositeType');

end.
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen, sorry I can't accept that I necessarily need a newer version of Delphi. I've heard of people who have achieved what I'm after with Delphi 7 and the updated wsdlimp.exe from http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24535 . I think I've already modified my WCF service to produce a "flat wsdl" for use with BasicHttpBinding, so I just need to "import" it into a pas file. What I want is the wsdlimp command line (with options) that will avoid composite types and any other stuff that Delphi 7 doesn't like. I know it can be done.

Comment: @Sam: I wasn't aware that the WSDL importer had been put on-line; I will put that in my answer. When I have more time I will try to get you a command-line too, but that will be more like at the end of the week.